# SceneKit shadow on a transparent SCNFloor()

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, shadow

I have a `floor node`, on which I need to cast shadow from `directional light`. This node needs to be transparent (used in `AR` environment).
And this works fine when I use `ARKit`, but the same setup using `SceneKit` shows no shadow or reflection. How can I cast a shadow in `SceneKit` like this? 
The problem with SceneKit is caused by the fact, that I set `sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear` - but I need this behaviour in this app. Can this be somehow avoided?

Sample code, demonstrating this issue (works only on device, not in simulator):

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView! {
    didSet {

        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode

        let testNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0))
        testNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(testNode)

        let animation = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 3.0)
        testNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(animation), completionHandler: nil)

        let floor = SCNFloor()
        floor.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
        floor.firstMaterial!.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
        floor.firstMaterial!.writesToDepthBuffer = true
        floor.firstMaterial!.lightingModel = .constant
        let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
        floorNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -2, z: 0)
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)

        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = .directional
        light.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        light.color = UIColor.white
        light.castsShadow = true
        light.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
        light.shadowMode = .deferred
        let sunLightNode = SCNNode()
        sunLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 1_000, y: 1_000, z: 0)
        sunLightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: .pi * 1.5)
        sunLightNode.light = light
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(sunLightNode)

        let omniLightNode: SCNNode = {
            let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
            let light: SCNLight = {
                let light = SCNLight()
                light.type = .omni
                return light
            }()
            omniLightNode.light = light
            return omniLightNode
        }()
        sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleTransparent))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
}

@objc func toggleTransparent() {
    transparent = !transparent
}

var transparent = false {
    didSet {
        sceneView.backgroundColor = transparent ? .clear : .white
    }
}
```

Here is the same example for macOS, build on top of SceneKit game project:

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        let testNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0))
        testNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(testNode)

        let animation = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 3.0)
        testNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(animation), completionHandler: nil)

        let floor = SCNFloor()
        floor.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
        floor.firstMaterial!.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
        floor.firstMaterial!.writesToDepthBuffer = true
        floor.firstMaterial!.lightingModel = .constant
        let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
        floorNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -2, z: 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)

        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = .directional
        light.shadowColor = NSColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        light.color = NSColor.white
        light.castsShadow = true
        light.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
        light.shadowMode = .deferred
        let sunLightNode = SCNNode()
        sunLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 1_000, y: 1_000, z: 0)
        sunLightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: .pi * 1.5)
        sunLightNode.light = light
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sunLightNode)

        let omniLightNode: SCNNode = {
            let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
            let light: SCNLight = {
                let light = SCNLight()
                light.type = .omni
                return light
            }()
            omniLightNode.light = light
            return omniLightNode
        }()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = .clear
//        scnView.backgroundColor = .white // shadow works in this mode, but I need it to be clear
    }
}
```

Sample projects:

MacOS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1o50mbgzg4gc0fg/Test_macOS.zip?dl=1

iOS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk71oay1sopc1vp/Test.zip?dl=1

In macOS you can change backgroundColor in last line of ViewController - I need it to be clear, so I can show camera preview under it.

On pictures below you can see what it looks like when sceneView.backgroundColor is white, and below - clear. On clear version there is no shadow.

[image: Here you can see this effect with white background color of sceneView - shadow is visible]

[image: And this if version with sceneView.backgroundColor == .clear. There is UIImageView under this view. I need to use this version, but there is no shadow visible]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are two steps to get a transparent shadow :

**First** : You need to connect it as a `node` to the `scene`, not as a `geometry type`.

```
let floor = SCNNode()
floor.geometry = SCNFloor()
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.writesToDepthBuffer = true
floor.geometry?.firstMaterial!.lightingModel = .constant
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floor)
```

Shadow on invisible SCNFloor():
[image]

Shadow on visible SCNPlane() and our camera is under SCNFloor():
[image]

> For getting a `transparent shadow` you need to set a `shadow color`, not the `object's transparency itself`.

**Second** : A `shadow color` must be set like this for macOS:

```
lightNode.light!.shadowColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0,
                                               green: 0, 
                                                blue: 0, 
                                               alpha: 0.5)
```

...and for iOS it looks like this:

```
lightNode.light!.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
```

Alpha component here (`alpha: 0.5`) is an `opacity` of the shadow and RGB components (`white: 0`) is black color of the shadow.

[image]

[image]

**P.S.**

> **`sceneView.backgroundColor` switching between `.clear` colour and `.white` colour**.

In this particular case I can't catch a robust shadow when `sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear`, because you need to switch between `RGBA=1,1,1,1` (**white mode**: white colour, alpha=1) and `RGBA=0,0,0,0` (**clear mode**: black colour, alpha=0).

In order to see semi-transparent shadow on a background the components should be `RGB=1,1,1` and `A=0.5`, but these values are whitening the image due to internal compositing mechanism of SceneKit. But when I set `RGB=1,1,1` and `A=0.02` the shadow is very feeble.

Here's a tolerable workaround for now (**look for solution below in SOLUTION section**):

```
@objc func toggleTransparent() {
    transparent = !transparent
}  
var transparent = false {
    didSet {
        // this shadow is very FEEBLE and it's whitening BG image a little bit
        sceneView.backgroundColor = 
                        transparent ? UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.02) : .white
    }
}

let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .directional

if transparent == false {
    light.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.9)
}
```

If I set `light.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1)` I'll get **satisfactory shadow** on BG image but **solid black shadow** on white.

[image]

> **SOLUTION**:
>
> **You should grab a render of 3D objects to have premultiplied RGBA image with its useful Alpha channel. After that, you can composite `rgba image of cube and its shadow` over `image of nature` using classical `OVER` compositing operation in another View.**

Here's a formula for `OVER` operation :

> **(RGB1 * A1) + (RGB2 * (1 – A1))**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181331/discussion-on-answer-by-gigantic-scenekit-shadow-on-a-transparent-scnfloor).

Comment: I guess it's not perfect solution, so I'm exploring some other ways to resolve this. I have noticed, that shadows are displayed when shadowColor is different then black. The closer color is to black the more transparent it gets. I managed to display only white shadow for now. Maybe this will help somehow.

Comment: What solution are you talking about? Compositing Over operation `(RGB1 * A1) + (RGB2 * (1 – A1))` or `UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.02)` ??

Comment: From what I see above, it's making background layer a little washed out, right?

Comment: Yes, Although I didn't try it, as I saw in your pictures that it's a little washed out, and I'm not sure how to apply this composition

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISourceOverCompositing

look for `CISourceOverCompositing`. It uses such operands as CICategoryStillImage and CICategoryVideo.

Comment: @ARGeo  Can you please please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073121/the-correct-way-to-add-direction-light-to-virtual-object-and-not-be-affected-by

Answer (score 4):

It's been awhile since this was posted but maybe someone will find this alternative solution useful. I encountered a similar situation and what I ended up doing was rendering using multiple passes via `SCNTechnique`. First I rendered a floor with a solid white `diffuse` and then I rendered the rest of the scene without the floor. To do this I set the `categoryBitMask` of my `SCNFloor` to 3 and left the others with the default value of 1.

Next I created my `SCNTechnique` with this definition which renders the floor and the rest of the scene into separate buffers and then combines them together into the final scene:

```
self.sceneView.technique = SCNTechnique(dictionary: [
  "passes" : [
    "store-floor": [
      "draw" : "DRAW_NODE",
      "node" : "floor-node",
      "inputs" : [],
      "outputs" : [ "color" : "color_floor" ]
    ],
    "store-scene": [
      "draw" : "DRAW_SCENE",
      "excludeCategoryMask" : 2,
      "inputs" : [],
      "outputs" : [ "color" : "color_scene" ]
    ],
    "recall-scene": [
      "draw" : "DRAW_QUAD",
      "metalVertexShader" : "vertex_tecnique_basic",
      "metalFragmentShader" : "fragment_tecnique_merge",
      "inputs" : [ "alphaTex" : "color_floor", "sceneTex" : "color_scene" ],
      "outputs" : [ "color" : "COLOR" ]
    ]
  ],
  "symbols" : [
    "vertexSymbol" : [ "semantic" : "vertex" ]
  ],
  "targets" : [
    "color_floor" : [ "type" : "color" ],
    "color_scene" : [ "type" : "color" ],
  ],
  "sequence" : [
    "store-floor",
    "store-scene",
    "recall-scene"
  ]
])
```

Next the Metal share code that takes those two buffers and combines them together where the alpha value ranges from 0 for white to 1 for black.

```
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct TechniqueVertexIn
{
    float4 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
};

struct TechniqueVertexOut
{
  float4 framePos [[position]];
  float2 centeredLoc;
};

constexpr sampler s = sampler(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::linear);

vertex TechniqueVertexOut vertex_tecnique_basic(
  TechniqueVertexIn     in [[stage_in]],
  constant SCNSceneBuffer&  scnFrame [[buffer(0)]])
{
  TechniqueVertexOut vert;

  vert.framePos = float4(in.position.x, in.position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  vert.centeredLoc = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);

  return vert;
}

fragment half4 fragment_tecnique_merge(
  TechniqueVertexOut  vert [[stage_in]],
  texture2d<float>  alphaTex [[texture(0)]],
  texture2d<float>  sceneTex [[texture(1)]])
{
    float4 alphaColor = alphaTex.sample(s, vert.centeredLoc);
    float4 sceneColor = sceneTex.sample(s, vert.centeredLoc);
  float alpha     = 1.0 - max(max(alphaColor.r, alphaColor.g), alphaColor.b); // since floor should be white, could just pick a chan

  alpha *= alphaColor.a;
  alpha = max(sceneColor.a, alpha);

  return half4(half3(sceneColor.rgb * alpha), alpha);
}
```

Lastly here's an example of what that ends up looking like with all the pieces put together.[image]