# Directional Light is affected by Camera's movement

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to achieve the shadows effect like in IKEA Place, where the shadow is stick with the virtual object.

[image]

Here is my implementation. I added the direction light and shadow plane to the virtual object. When I moved the virtual object in the scene, shadow is not positioned right under the bottom of the virtual object.

Here is my code:

```
func setupShadows() {

    let flourPlane = SCNFloor()
    let groundPlane = SCNNode()
    let groundMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    groundMaterial.lightingModel = .constant
    groundMaterial.writesToDepthBuffer = true
    groundMaterial.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
    groundMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = []
    flourPlane.materials = [groundMaterial]
    groundPlane.geometry = flourPlane
    addChildNode(groundPlane)

    // Create a ambient light
    let ambientLight = SCNNode()
    ambientLight.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLight.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
    ambientLight.light?.color = UIColor.white
    ambientLight.light?.type = .ambient
    addChildNode(ambientLight)

    // Create a directional light node with shadow
    let directionalLightNode = SCNNode()
    directionalLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    directionalLightNode.light?.type = .directional
    directionalLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.white
    directionalLightNode.light?.castsShadow = true
    directionalLightNode.light?.automaticallyAdjustsShadowProjection = true
    directionalLightNode.light?.shadowMode = .deferred
    directionalLightNode.light?.categoryBitMask = -1
    directionalLightNode.light?.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    directionalLightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: .pi * 1.5)
    addChildNode(directionalLightNode)
}
```

Comment: I think maybe there is a bug in SceneKit or ARKit. I tested this on iOS 12.3, it's ok. But on 13.1, it's not.

Comment: Please, publish all the code.

Comment: @ARGeo Thanks for the comment. 

Here is how I set up the light.
https://github.com/xieweizhi/shadow_issue_on_ios13.1/blob/master/ARKitInteraction/Virtual%20Objects/VirtualObject.swift#L65

Comment: You can test the shadow using the chair model. This is the example project provided by Apple.

Comment: I tried different scenarios but can't get an issue you're talking about. What's your code? Not the Apple code you gave me.

Comment: Same way to set up the light and shadow plane? Can you please send me the codes?

Comment: The same codes work great on iOS 12.3.

Comment: what's your phone model?

Comment: iPhone 7 plus, xs max

Comment: For static shadow you can add shadow in your 3d object. Do not use Light. @Weizhi

Comment: @KomalGoyani Thanks for your reply. Our team has considered this solution. But the 3d model team can't produce the shadow texture at the moment.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?  I encountered a very similar case in our app. The shadows seems moves with the camera.  It did show up after upgrading to iOS 13.  I have to disable the shadow before finding the correct solution.

Comment: Hey @EricWong. We finally solved the problem by creating the shawod 3d obj ourselves instead of creating it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it with the same method.  Just can't find out a direct solution anymore.